# Tools to check system startup speed

Tags: startup

Since Maverick Upgrade startup performances are not so good as previous versions. In particular after I log in desktop is really slow to become available to use. From grub to gdm everything is fine and fast as expected. How can I find out which elements slow down desktop loading? I've disabled all useless stuffs to me in `Startup Applications`, but still I cannot obtain fair performances. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the alternative (bootchart) I posted here: [Intense hard drive access activity immediately after log in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12900/intense-hard-drive-access-activity-immediately-after-log-in/12904#12904)

Comment: Your trick can be the solution, thanks, I'm investigating.

Answer (score 1):

BootChart is the definitive tool. Here is a helpful explanation:

> Bootchart is a tool for performance analysis and visualization of the GNU/Linux boot process. Resource utilization and process information are collected during the boot process and are later rendered in a PNG, SVG or EPS encoded chart.

Install it (open a terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install bootchart
```

Visit the [BootChart.org](http://www.bootchart.org/) website for documentation and how-to use it. And dont forget to report a bug in case you find one.

Comment: I knew about bootchart, but by default it stops monitoring after gdm screen. I'm using htorque's trick to investigate what happens just after I log in.

Comment: @skalka: They changed it a few Ubuntu versions ago to keep recording for 45 seconds after GDM by default. So you can still see what happens after you login. Also see this question: http://superuser.com/questions/32919/is-there-a-bootchart-style-analyzer-for-what-happens-after-you-log-in

Comment: @Matthew: the charts get cropped after compiz, metacity, mutter, kwin, or xfwm4 is loaded (using bootchart's '--crop-after' parameter).